# running java command in python

Tags: java, python

I am trying to run a java command in python

```
java = subprocess.call(['java', '-version'])
```

and I keep getting..

```
java = subprocess.call(['java', '-version'])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-28-000f611bf425>", line 1, in <module>
    java = subprocess.call(['java', '-version'])

  File "C:\Users\shapi\Anaconda3\envs\stanfordnlp\lib\subprocess.py", line 317, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:

  File "C:\Users\shapi\Anaconda3\envs\stanfordnlp\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 105, in __init__
    super(SubprocessPopen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\shapi\Anaconda3\envs\stanfordnlp\lib\subprocess.py", line 769, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "C:\Users\shapi\Anaconda3\envs\stanfordnlp\lib\subprocess.py", line 1172, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I can run java programs by calling them without the java prefix e.g. the following works, but if cmd = 'java hello_world.java' then even though it works in command line
it returns an error code 1 in python.

```
#Run Java File
cmd = 'hello_world.java'
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: try it with the full path to the executable

Comment: As an aside, you should be using `subprocess.run` instead, `subprocess.call` is an older API that is kept around for compatibility purposes